# How to create a collection of Expression<Func<T, TRelated>>?

Tags: linq, linq-to-nhibernate, linq-expressions, specification-pattern

I have a repository with the following method:

```
IEnumerable<T> FindAll<TRelated>(Specification<T> specification,
                                 Expression<Func<T, TRelated>> fetchExpression);
```

I need to pass in more than one expression. I was thinking about changing the signature to:

```
IEnumerable<T> FindAll<TRelated>(Specification<T> specification, 
                                 IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, TRelated>>> fetchExpression);
```

1. Is this possible?
2. How do I create an array, say, of expressions to pass into this method?

Currently I'm calling the method from my service layer like this:

```
var products = productRepository.FindAll(specification,p => p.Variants);
```

But I'd like to pass `p => p.Variants` and `p => p.Reviews` for example. And then in the repository I'd like to iterate through the expression and add them to a query.

For a bit of background on why I am doing this see Ben Foster's blog post on [Eager loading with NHibernate](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Eager-loading-with-NHibernate-LINQ.aspx).

Comment: I didn't know [Ben Foster](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004936/) was a programmer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use params to do it:

```
IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Specification<T> specification,
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] fetchExpressions)
{
    var query = GetQuery(specification);
    foreach(var fetchExpression in fetchExpressions)
    {
        query.Fetch(fetchExpression);
    }
    return query.ToList();
}
```

You can call this like so:

```
var products = productRepository.FindAll(specification,
        p => p.Variants, p => p.Reviews );
```

Comment: The `params` way is great, but how do you execute the expressions when they are an `IEnumerable`? Joining the `Query<T>()` with the fetchExpressions?

Comment: Fixed it to use object instead of TRelated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your call to this:

```
var products = productRepository.FindAll(specification,
                                         new [] { p => p.Variants, 
                                                  p => p.Reviews });
```

But this will only work if the `T` is the same in both!